# Using CSV Type Provider on a directory F#

Tags: file, parsing, csv, f#, directory

I'm tring to use CSV type provider to store in a sequence the sum of a column in each file in a directory. I'm using the following code, but its giving me incorrect values when I print the sequence. When I write it to read only one file, it provides the correct value. I don't know what is happening differently when I try to run it over all the files in the directory.

```
let dir = new DirectoryInfo("..\adr-financials\adr-sales")
type SalesReport = CsvProvider<"..\adr-financials\adr-sales\sales.txt", Separators="\t", IgnoreErrors=true>
let sales = 
    [for file in dir.GetFiles() do
        let salesReport = SalesReport.Load(file.FullName)
        let totalSales =
            salesReport.Rows
            |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.``Extended Partner Share``)
            |> Seq.filter (fun elem -> not (Double.IsNaN (float(elem))))
            |> Seq.sum
        yield totalSales]
for sale in sales do
    printfn "%f" sale
```

I've also tried writing it where the Csv Provider is defined within the for loop, but that gives me an error "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression"

Comment: Are you expecting dir.GetFiles() to return filenames in a specific order? The reason I ask is maybe you comparing your results with the wrong files?

Comment: The CSV type provider works well when all your files have the same structure (i.e. same column names in the same order). Is that the true for your files?

Comment: Yes they all have the exact same structure. For some reason it seems like it's messing up in the middle of the sequence.

Comment: I don't know if this has been fixed yet, but there was a time when the CSV type provider would stop yielding rows if one line of the file had, for example, a quote character in the middle of a value.  Maybe see if you can narrow the issue down to one file and look carefully at its contents?

Comment: Can you provide an example CSV file in your question?